# firebase storage android sdk throws storage exception

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

this is quite weird

when i m trying to handle a file using RX in background using the following code

```
// this code lies in a RX statement
FirebaseStorage
    .getInstance()
    .getReference(path) // file path. which does not exist
    .getDownloadUrl()
    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
            String url = task.getResult().toString();
            MyLogger.logMessage(TAG, url);
            // here i have some logic to handle file 
        } else {
            MyLogger.logError(TAG, "error getting url : " + task.getException());
            emitter.onError(new Throwable(task.getException()));
        }
    });
```

it throws the following error and the app crashes.

```
2019-12-14 13:29:26.835 327-918/com E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2019-12-14 13:29:26.837 327-918/com E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:438)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:455)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:446)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:279)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:293)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.0.0:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

when i do the same stuff on main thread, it throws error but app doesn't crash

I know code is perfect.

I also tried implementing different success and failure listener but of no use same thing happens.

I know the file does not exist at location.

I'm not concerned about file but the error handling.

Why is app crashing even when I'm properly handling the error?

This question has already been asked, but has not been answered anywhere.

Comment: Are you saying that your `addOnCompleteListener` callback is not invoked when the file does not exist?

Comment: yes
it is invoked but the app also crashes

Comment: Woudln't that be the expected result with your call to `emitter.onError(new Throwable(task.getException()));`?

Comment: why would it happen
i m properly handling the error in my implementation

Comment: It's fairly simple: remove the `emitter.onError(new Throwable(task.getException()));` statement. If the error in your app then still remains, Firebase is likely throwing it elsewhere. If the error disappears without the `emitter.onError(new Throwable(task.getException()));` statement, it's clearly coming from somewhere else in your application, and it'll be impossible to say more based on the code you shared, and it's probably better to reproduce the problem in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that Rx experts are more likely to look at.

Comment: ok thanks. no problem. but that thing didnt work

Comment: "that thing didn't work" is not really helpful here. Once you remove the `emitter.onError(new Throwable(task.getException()));`, what happens? Does the app still crash with the exact same error in that case?

Comment: but i want to handle the error. i dont want to ignore it

Comment: Please read my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333480/firebase-storage-android-sdk-throws-storage-exception?noredirect=1#comment104878001_59333480): the code you currently show in your question is behaving as expected. You can either handle the missing file in the `else` block of this code, or higher up the chain (which you didn't show)

Comment: seriously there is no problem in the handling part i m just logging the error thats it

Comment: i think there is some threading problem. i need to talk to some RX guy